# Enlazar web con php

Tags: php

Estoy realizando una base de datos y tengo una duda. Tengo un index con el siguiente codigo:

Buenas,

Estoy realizando una base de datos y tengo una duda. Tengo un index con el siguiente codigo:

```
    <p align="center">
    <label><input type="radio" name="serue" value="serie"> Nova sèrie</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="temporada" value="temporada"> Nova temporada</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="qualificar" value="qualificar"> Qualificar una temporada</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="dades" value="dades"> Dades d'una sèrie</label>
    </p>

    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Tria una opció"></p>

</form>
```

Lo que quiero es que de las 4 opciones, cada vez que se seleccione una de ellas, me lleve a un archivo php que me gestionara las opciones. Es decir, por cada opcion, se abrira una pagina web diferente.

El problema es que cuando selecciono una opcion, me lleva a un archivo .html y no al archivo .php que gestiona las opciones.

Quiero que al darle a una opcion, me lleve al archivo php y se carge una web diferente para cada opcion.

Mis archivos son:

index html
opciousuari php
novaserie html
temporada html
qualifcar html
dades html

Alguien me podria ayudar¿

Lo que quiero es que de las 4 opciones, cada vez que se seleccione una de ellas, me lleve a un archivo php que me gestionara las opciones. Es decir, por cada opcion, se abrira una pagina web diferente.

El problema es que cuando selecciono una opcion, me lleva a un archivo .html y no al archivo .php que gestiona las opciones.

Quiero que al darle a una opcion, me lleve al archivo php y se carge una web diferente para cada opcion.

Mis archivos son:

```
index.html
opciousuari.php
novaserie.html
temporada.html
qualifcar.html
dades.html
```

Alguien me podria ayudar¿

Comment: podrias clarificar tu pregunta?? esta muy cnfusa

Comment: Tengo un index con 4 opciones. Esas 4 opciones tiene su .html respectivamente. Pero la gestion de esos 4.html tiene que ser a traves de un archivo .php. Cuando el usuario eliga una opcion, quiero que me lleve al archivo.php pero con la pagina web que le corresponda

Comment: He resuelto la duda, pero me queda por resolver lo siguiente: Como puedo hacer que el isset del php coga el "value" del formulario y no el "name"?

Comment: Considera colocar siempre el código donde estás teniendo problema. En cuanto a tu último comentario, cuando un formulario es enviado los elementos del mismo son serializados en un array, donde la clave es lo que haya en la etiqueta `name` de cada elemento y el valor es lo que haya en la etiqueta `value`. De modo que el dato del `value` lo encontrarás con algo como esto: `$_POST['loQueHayaEnName'];` Ahí estará el contenido del  `value`.

Comment: Pero si mi forumlario tiene 4 inpunts con un name diferente, en $_POST["name"] no va a poder distingit a que input me refiero, no?